# Subtracting multiple values in a dbgrid where records in a certain column change

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2010

I have built an `Access` database and connected it with an `ADOquery` and `Datasource`.I have built a table named `StockSales` which has the following fields and records. [StockSales Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Pc79.jpg).
I have attached a `DBgrid` into a form and linked it with the `StockSales` table.
 If a customer purchases a product, I have the following code which works fine according to what the customer buys using the `ProductSale`column. It subtracts the `stocksIn` and adds `StockOut` according to what the customer buys in `ProductSale`.

the following code is what I have used to do the computation

```
 `procedure TSalesForm.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);`
  var sales : string;
  begin
   sales:=  SalesADOQuery.FieldByName('product').Asstring;
    if SalesADOQuery.Locate('product', sales, []) then begin
    SalesADOQuery.edit;
    SalesADOQuery.FieldByName('stockIn').AsFloat:= 
    (SalesADOQuery.FieldByName('stockIn').AsFloat- 
    SalesADOQuery.FieldByName('ProductSale').AsFloat);

    SalesADOQuery.FieldByName('stockOut').AsFloat:= 
    (SalesADOQuery.FieldByName('stockOut').AsFloat + 
    SalesADOQuery.FieldByName('ProductSale').AsFloat);
    SalesADOQuery.Post;
 showmessage('stock successfully updated');
end;
end;`
```

If for instance I enter 50 in ProductSale, results will be 950 for StockIn and 50 for StockOut [StockTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n9Bq.jpg).
I want a code that is able to recognize the values of the `ProductSale` that have changed. If I put different values for random products that a customer buys in the`Dbgrid`, once I have accomplished putting the relevant values in the `ProductSale` column then press `BitBtn2`, it will only change the `stockIn` and `StockOut` columns where a customer has bought a product. It has to do calculations similar to the code for `BitBtn1` then displays the results in the columns for `StockIn` and `StockOut` only for the products that have been purchased in the `dbgrid`

Comment: I doubt it is helpful to think in terms of what is displayed in the grid. If user1 makes some changes to the SaleAmounts, what is user2 supposed to see, and when?  You should consider having a SalesHistory table.  Then, the problem would become relatively trivial.

Comment: The system user is the seller only, not the customer. I did this specifically to avoid using text boxes to search and save a single product all the time but instead I thought a DbGrid will be able to calculate fast what I edit then as soon as I am satisfied I save all the changes for history to another table with a different button. However, I don't know whether this is the best approach, unless there are other alternatives.

Comment: @MartynA this is also a simplified table suitable for the problem, else there are other colunms about pricing I removed for simplicity.

Comment: Well, your fundamental mistake is to think that a DBGrid does any calculation, it does not and cannot - all it does is to display the column values in the underlying dataset.  You would do best, imo, to consider what business functions you want to provide and then specify the dataset operations necessary to implement them.  Anyway, I'm done so good luck.

Comment: @MartynA I have been using calculated fields from a dataset using the OnCalcFields property of the dataset before, then link the DBgrid with the dataset.